# XSLT 1.0 to concatenate elements

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a XML which has complex element called ExternalRequestIDs,
My requirement is to concatenate the ExternalRequestID values coming at run time.
If the input has 5 ExternalRequestID values then the 5 values needs to be concatenated.
The XSL i have created perform only static translation, am trying to accomplish this logic in xslt 1.0, i am new to xslt Please help

Source XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RetrieveMIProcessRequest xmlns="http://xmlns.mycompany.com/RetrieveMI">
   <ExternalRequestIDs>
      <ExternalRequestID>ID1</ExternalRequestID>
   </ExternalRequestIDs>
   <ExternalRequestIDs>
      <ExternalRequestID>ID2</ExternalRequestID>
   </ExternalRequestIDs>
   <ExternalRequestIDs>
      <ExternalRequestID>ID3</ExternalRequestID>
   </ExternalRequestIDs>
   <SourceSystem>SourceSystemName</SourceSystem>
 </RetrieveMIProcessRequest>
```

Transformation Created to Concatenate ExternalRequestID values -

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest>
      <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest/ns0:ExternalRequestIDs">
        <xsl:variable name="ExtId"
                      select="concat(&quot;'&quot;,/ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest/ns0:ExternalRequestIDs[1]/ns0:ExternalRequestID,&quot;','&quot;,/ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest/ns0:ExternalRequestIDs[2]/ns0:ExternalRequestID&quot;'&quot;)"/>
        <ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
          <ns0:ExternalRequestID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$ExtId"/>
          </ns0:ExternalRequestID>
        </ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <ns0:SourceSystem>
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest/ns0:SourceSystem"/>
      </ns0:SourceSystem>
          </ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest>
  </xsl:template>
```

Output after transformation -

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.mycompany.com/RetrieveMI">
   <ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
      <ns0:ExternalRequestID>'ID1','ID2'</ns0:ExternalRequestID>
   </ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
   <ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
      <ns0:ExternalRequestID>'ID1','ID2'</ns0:ExternalRequestID>
   </ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
   <ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
      <ns0:ExternalRequestID>'ID1','ID2'</ns0:ExternalRequestID>
   </ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
   <ns0:SourceSystem>SourceSystemName</ns0:SourceSystem>

</ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest>
```

Expected Output -

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.mycompany.com/RetrieveMI">
<ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
 <ns0:ExternalRequestID>'ID1','ID2','ID3'</ns0:ExternalRequestID>
</ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
  <ns0:SourceSystem>SourceSystemName</ns0:SourceSystem>

</ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest>
```

This needs to be achieved at run based on the ExternalRequestID values coming in the input request.
If the input has 5 ExternalRequestID values then the values needs to be concatenated

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to obtain the output you show us (the actual output, not the expected one) with such a stylesheet. Can you update your question?

Comment: My requirement is to concatenate the ExternalRequestID values from the request and map it to response..If there are 5 ExternalRequestID values all needs to be concatenated and mapped to response.Is there any other to accomplish in XSLT 1.0

Comment: Can you also explain how you retrieve the `ID1`, ... value? Is it only a substring of `ExternalRequestID1`?

Comment: Edited my question..<ExternalRequestID> values alone needs to concatenated, no need to take substring, am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this template should fit your needs :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest>
            <ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
                <ns0:ExternalRequestID>
                    <!-- Loop on all ExternalRequestID and concatenate the textual values -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest/ns0:ExternalRequestIDs/ns0:ExternalRequestID">
                        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:if test="following::ns0:ExternalRequestID">
                            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ns0:ExternalRequestID>
            </ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
        <ns0:SourceSystem>
            <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest/ns0:SourceSystem"/>
        </ns0:SourceSystem>
    </ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest>
</xsl:template>
```

The output I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.mycompany.com/RetrieveMI">
    <ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
      <ns0:ExternalRequestID>'ID1','ID2','ID3'</ns0:ExternalRequestID>
    </ns0:ExternalRequestIDs>
  <ns0:SourceSystem>SourceSystemName</ns0:SourceSystem>
</ns0:RetrieveMIProcessRequest>
```